# Proof verification: quantile functions inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let lower and upper quantile functions be defined as follows:

$F^{-}(\alpha) = \inf\left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$

$F^{+}(\alpha) = \sup\left \{ x: F(x) \leq  \alpha \right \}$

where $F(x) = P\left (\left (-\infty, x   \right ] \right) $ - is a CDF; it's right continuous and non decreasing.

One is asked to prove that

> $\forall \alpha \in (0, 1): F^{−}(\alpha) \leq F^{+}(\alpha)$

---

First, I show that $F^{-}(\alpha) \in \left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$ (and thus $F^{-}(\alpha) = \min \left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$):

Suppose it's not the case and $m=F^{-}(\alpha) \not\in \left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$. Then $F(m) < \alpha$.

Let $\epsilon_{0} = \alpha - F(m)$. As $F(x)$ is right continuous then $\exists \delta \ \ \forall y \ \ 0 \leq y-m < \delta \ \ 0 \leq F(y) - F(m) < \epsilon_{0}$ and $F(y) < \alpha$ (because $F(y) < F(m) + \epsilon_{0} < F(m) + \alpha - F(m) = \alpha$). Thus $F^{-}(\alpha)$ is not the infinum of $\left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$. Contradiction.

---

Let's now consider two cases:

Case 1:

$\exists x_{0}: F(x_{0})=\alpha$. I show that $F^{-}(\alpha) \leq F^{+}(\alpha)$:

$x_{0} \in \left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \}$ and $x_{0} \in \left \{ x: F(x) \leq  \alpha \right \}$. This implies $x_{0} \geq F^{-}(\alpha)$, and thus $F^{+}(\alpha)=\sup \left \{ x: F(x) \leq  \alpha \right \} \geq x_{0} \geq\inf \left \{ x: F(x) \geq  \alpha \right \} = F^{-}(\alpha)$.

Case 2:

$\not\exists x: F(x)=\alpha$. I show that $F^{-}(\alpha) = \sup \left \{x : F(x) \leq \alpha \right \} = F^{+}(\alpha)$

As $F$ is non decreasing, 
$\forall x \in \left \{x : F(x) \leq \alpha \right \} \ \ x < \min \left \{x : F(x) \geq \alpha \right \} = F^{-}(\alpha)$. 
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \ \ m=F^{-}(\alpha) - \epsilon \not \in \left \{ x : F(x) \geq \alpha \right \} $ thus $F(m) < \alpha$ and $m \in \left \{x : F(x) \leq \alpha \right \}$ and thus $F^{-}(\alpha)=\sup \left \{x : F(x) \leq \alpha \right \} = F^{+}(\alpha)$

I'd appreciate any remarks re: validity and advice on how the proof could be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're proof work, let me try to simplify it a bit.

I will just assume that $F:\mathbb{R}\to (0,1)$ is nondecreasing. Notice that the sets $A:=\{x:F(x)\leq\alpha\}$ and $B:=\{x:F(x)\geq\alpha\}$ completely cover $\mathbb{R}$, and that every element $a\in A$ is not larger than any element $b\in B$,by the fact that the function is increasing. But then, if $\sup A<\inf B$, the number $\frac{\sup A+\inf B}{2}$ could not be in either $A$ or $B$, a contradiction.

Comment: Brilliant, I definitely overthought the problem